# How to get the end of continuous value update for Gtk Spinbox?

Tags: event-handling, gtk

I'm using Gtk2 to make a small tool, it works like this:

- Several *Scale*s and *Spinbox*es control parameters of an algorithm.
- When parameter changes, the algorithm will execute, and the updated result is rendered as a picture, shown in UI.

As the algorithm's workload is heavy, I don't want it run frequently during frequent parameter change. Specifically, during *Scales* are dragged or *Spinbox*'s arrows buttons are pressed. Instead, I want the algorithm to be run "after" users have determined the parameters.

Currently, I listened the *button-release* event of the *Scale*s, so the algorithm will run only on *Scale* dragging is done. However, this not fit for the *Spinboxe*s, as they have separate entry and button sub-area. If I listen to *Spinbox*'s *button-release*, it would behave weirdly.

So what event (or events) should I listen to obtain the occation that a continuous value update is finished for a Spinbox?

Answer (score 0):

Could I see the code you have? The *button-release* works great for me. However, depending on your algorithm, you may be getting 'feedback'. Are you sure the rest of the code is not updating your spinbutton in some way?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a deferred computation, independent from the device you use to modify the data. In this way you can also input the numbers with the keyboard or copy and paste their content and the program will still work as expected.

A way to do this in GTK+ is by leveraging the main loop and using a timeout `GSource`, e.g.:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct {
    guint       event;
    GSourceFunc callback;
    GtkWidget  *spin_button;
} Algorithm;

static gboolean your_callback(Algorithm *algorithm)
{
    g_print("Your heavy computations go here...\n");
    /* ... */
    algorithm->event = 0;
    return FALSE;
}

static void postpone(Algorithm *algorithm)
{
    if (algorithm->event > 0) {
        g_source_remove(algorithm->event);
    }
    /* Default delay is 1 second (1000 milliseconds) */
    algorithm->event = g_timeout_add(1000, algorithm->callback, algorithm);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *window, *spin_button;
    Algorithm algorithm;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    spin_button = gtk_spin_button_new_with_range(0, 100, 0.1);
    g_signal_connect_swapped(spin_button, "value-changed",
                             G_CALLBACK(postpone), &algorithm);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), spin_button);

    algorithm.event       = 0;
    algorithm.callback    = (GSourceFunc) your_callback;
    algorithm.spin_button = spin_button;

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```